# Interpretation of Shivadvaitha

Tags: shiva

Vedantha and Nigamantha are different in terms of philosophy. Saiva Sidhantha is Agamic and if so, how is it different from vedantha or upanishads

Comment: Are u asking how is Shiva-Advaita-Vaad of Shrikantha-Shivaacharya Traditionally carried forwarded by Appayya Dikshit is different from Agamic Shaiva Siddhanta??